# Neural network in Theano with sparse weight matrix diverging

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparse-matrix, theano, gradient-descent

I am working on a neural network with very large sparse weight matrices. The zero values in the weights are to remain zero and not be changed. Gradients should only be calculated and propagated for non zero values since it will otherwise be too expensive to run. This means I am using Theano and its sparse.structured_dot matrix multiplication. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math
import numpy as np
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import sparse as sp
import scipy.sparse as spsp


def sparse_matrix(matrix, name):
    """Convert an array to a shared sparse theano matrix."""
    matrix = np.asarray(matrix)
    if matrix.shape[0] > matrix.shape[1]: matrix = spsp.csc_matrix(matrix)
    else: matrix = spsp.csr_matrix(matrix)
    return th.shared(matrix, name)


def mul(weight, matrix):
    """Sparse matrix multiplication.
    :param weight: sparse weight m x n matrix, where m is number of features of output and n is number of features for 
    input.
    :param matrix: input n x p matrix, where n is number of features for input and p is number of input vectors.
    """
    return T.transpose(sp.structured_dot(weight, T.transpose(matrix)))


x = T.fmatrix('x')
target = T.fmatrix('target')

W = sparse_matrix([[0, 0.5], [0.5, 0]], 'W')
y = mul(W, x)

cost = T.mean((y - target) ** 2) / 2
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=W)

W_updated = W - (gradient * 0.01)
updates = [(W, W_updated)]

f = th.function(inputs=[x, target], outputs=[y, cost, gradient], updates=updates, allow_input_downcast=True)

print("start weight:\n", W.get_value().todense())

for i in range(10):
    pred, c, g = f([[4.0, 2.0]], [[2.0, 4.0]])
    print("pred:", pred)
    print("cost:", c)
    print("grad:\n", g)

print("end weight:\n", W.get_value().todense())
```

The example I test is simple, the matrix values are supposed to both go from 0.5 to 1.0 where the cost will become zero. It however diverges, both values decrease and the gradients are always about 1.0 and 2.0. It seems the gradients are being calculated wrong. If I run the code I get the following output:

```
start weight:
 [[ 0.   0.5]
 [ 0.5  0. ]]
pred: [[ 1.  2.]]
cost: 1.25
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071339
  (1, 0)    2.00000143424
pred: [[ 0.97999999  1.91999994]]
cost: 1.3417000669408599
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071343
  (1, 0)    2.00000143439
pred: [[ 0.95999997  1.83999989]]
cost: 1.4368001387634612
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071347
  (1, 0)    2.00000143453
pred: [[ 0.93999996  1.75999983]]
cost: 1.5353002154685411
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.0000007135
  (1, 0)    2.00000143468
pred: [[ 0.91999994  1.67999977]]
cost: 1.637200297056838
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071354
  (1, 0)    2.00000143483
pred: [[ 0.89999993  1.59999971]]
cost: 1.7425003835290889
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071358
  (1, 0)    2.00000143498
pred: [[ 0.87999991  1.51999966]]
cost: 1.8512004748860316
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071362
  (1, 0)    2.00000143513
pred: [[ 0.8599999  1.4399996]]
cost: 1.9633005711284035
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071365
  (1, 0)    2.00000143528
pred: [[ 0.83999989  1.35999954]]
cost: 2.0788006722569428
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071369
  (1, 0)    2.00000143543
pred: [[ 0.81999987  1.27999948]]
cost: 2.197700778272387
grad:
   (0, 1)   1.00000071373
  (1, 0)    2.00000143558
end weight:
 [[ 0.          0.39999993]
 [ 0.29999986  0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought CSR and CSC sparse matrices were supposed to act the same in this context, hence the sparse_matrix function picks one based on the matrix dimensions. However it turns out that my problem is fixed if I explicitly use CSC and avoid CSR. Then, the values in the sparse matrix converges to 1.0 and the cost disappears.